# How to transfer the Facebook instance articles from one WordPress to another WordPress with same domain name?

Tags: facebook

I want to ask one thing that, I changed the server with the different IP to storage increase. But I face one issue that my site already has the **Facebook instance article** access in the old server.
The thing I want to know is how can I transfer the **Facebook instance article** account from one server to another with same domain name?

Comment: If it's the same domain name then Facebook shouldn't notice the change I wouldn't have thought, unless you configured the articles on Facebook by IP address? (I assume you're migrating the whole site and database, so you're not likely to lose any Facebook metadata attached to the posts in WordPress, although I don't know Instant Articles so I don't know if / what that would be. If you are setting up a new WordPress instance from scratch then I'd check the Facebook plugin settings and if there's any post meta attached to your article posts.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I register the instance article with the domain name. But I worry about the viewer of the new server. The viewer of the new server is a little bit.